# global alias on sSMTP revaliases file

Tags: ssmtp

To send mail with sSMTP you have to add aliases for each user on /etc/ssmtp/revaliases

My issue:

- User "user1" tries to send mail with ssmtp
- user1 don't have an entry in revaliases file
- ssmtp generates FROM of the mail like this: user1@mymail@gmail.com
- This causes an error from gmail "553 5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by auth user."

My question: Is there a way to use all users same alias? Because I don't want to add same alias entry into the revaliases file for all users.